# Why is my Maven project packaging test files?

Tags: java, maven

I have a Maven project which I'm trying to package, but I've noticed that all my Java test classes (but none of my Scala test classes) and generated Avro test classes are ending up in the jar.

Folder structure looks fine:

[image]

I also noticed that if I add junit as a dependency with `<scope>test</scope>`, my tests won't compile as it can't find the junit classes, so it looks like Maven is treating all my code including tests as being part of main.

Pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.me</groupId>
    <artifactId>proj</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>

    <properties>
        <log4j.version>2.8.1</log4j.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        ...
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
                <artifactId>scalatest-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>scala-compile-first</id>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-source</goal>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>scala-test-compile</id>
                        <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <scalaVersion>2.11.8</scalaVersion>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
                <artifactId>avro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.8.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>schema</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/resources/</sourceDirectory>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/java</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-sources</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Comment: Does this happen for tests written in java as well, or just for scala?

Comment: Look at this even if it's not exactly the same problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13157815/intellij-idea-sudenly-wont-recognize-tests-in-test-folder

Comment: @JiriTousek Now that I look at it, none of the Scala tests are in the jar, so it's just the Java ones.

Comment: Try to run `mvn clean package` in a command line to see if it's due to your IDE.

Comment: @SébastienTemprado Same result. I've even tried getting a different machine running Jenkins to pull and build and the jar is the exact same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

The issue was with the avro-maven-plugin.

It's configuration had `sourceDirectory` and `outputDirectory`, both of which had test source paths.

```
<configuration>
  <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/resources/</sourceDirectory>
  <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/java</outputDirectory>
</configuration>
```

Apparently these were interfering with the compiler plugin which thought that these directories were main source directories and compiled them along with the rest of the main classes. This also explains why my tests were failing to compile when the junit dependency was given a test scope.

The solution was to use `testSourceDirectory` and `testOutputDirectory` instead:

```
<configuration>
  <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/resources/</testSourceDirectory>
  <testOutputDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/java</testOutputDirectory>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score -4):

mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip=true -X

Comment: That will just skip the tests instead of solving the issue.